# New uploaded picture is not appearing until you restart the application in edit mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, inline, inline-editing

I have a project written in MVC 4.
I am using kendo grid for one of my partial view
below is a part of my code for my grid

```
 columns.Bound(p => p.BrandID).Groupable(false).Title(MyResources.LabelBrandID).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:" + MyResources.HeaderDirection });

 columns.Bound(p => p.BrandNameE).Title(MyResources.LabelBrandNameE).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:" + MyResources.HeaderDirection });
 columns.Bound(p => p.BrandNameA).Title(MyResources.LabelBrandNameA).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:" + MyResources.HeaderDirection });
 columns.Bound(p => p.BrandID).Width(120).Title(" ").Filterable(false).Sortable(false)
         .ClientTemplate(@"<img onError='BrandImgNotFound(this);' src='" + Url.Content("~/Images/Brands/") + "#=data.BrandID#.jpg'  />");        
 columns.Template(@<text></text>).Title(" ").ClientTemplate("<input type=file name='files' onchange='dataBound(this.value)' />").Width(280).Hidden(true);                 
 columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text(MyResources.EditText).CancelText(MyResources.CancelText).UpdateText(MyResources.UpdateText); command.Destroy().Text(MyResources.Delete); });
```

My problem is when you are uploading picture in inline editing and store it in the folder by using `File.Copy`, 
new picture in edit mode is not appearing until you restart the application. 
although the new uploaded picture is available in the folder.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: After you add/upload the image, are you refreshing the data source of the grid?

Comment: thanks Neil, in add mode the picture( that you uploaded ) is appearing in kendo grid without you restart the application 
but in edit mode when you change the picture by uploading new picture, the old picture still appearing until you restart the application the new picture is appearing